# Extension method to format properties that are not null and not empty

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to work with the following class, which is inside a library I currently *cannot* change:

```
// This class represents "external" code as far as my review
// request is concerned: I cannot change this, currently.
public class AddressDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}
```

I'm writing an extension method with c# 5 and .NET 4.5.1 to represent instances of that class as a string for display purposes. I'm looking to get feedback on the inner workings of this method:

```
// Looking for feedback on this method:
public static string FormatForGui(this AddressDto Address)
{
    if (Address == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Address");

    var parts = new[] 
    {
        Address.Name,
        Address.AddressLine,
        Address.Zip,
        Address.City
    };

    return string.Join(" ", parts.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
}
```

Can this method body be improved?

---

For your convenience, here's a condensed NUnit unit test to define the behavior:

```
// Not necessarily looking for feedback on these tests, my actual tests are more DAMP 
// but for brevity I condensed them into one test:
[Test]
public void AllTests()
{
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => ((AddressDto)null).FormatForGui());
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo(""));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo(""));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "A" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo("A"));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "A", AddressLine = "B" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo("A B"));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "A", AddressLine = "B", Zip = "C" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo("A B C"));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "A", AddressLine = "B", Zip = "C", City = "D" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo("A B C D"));
    Assert.That(new AddressDto { Name = "A", AddressLine = "B", City = "D" }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo("A B D"));
}
```

Comment: The method is short and looks clear to me. What kind of improvement are you looking for?

Comment: Not worth an answer, but the methods parameter should be named using `camelCase` casing (based on the NET naming guidelines).

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for a review of a tiny amount of decent code, so there is not much to say.

---

```
return string.Join(" ", parts.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

You're first using `string` and then `String` to call a static method. You should be consistent in which one you use.

---

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("Address");
```

If you're using C# 6.0, you could use `nameof` here:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Address));
```

(And Heslacher already mentioned in a comment that it should be `address`.)

---

```
Assert.That(new AddressDto { }.FormatForGui(), Is.EqualTo(""));
```

I think that `Assert.AreEqual()` is better, mostly since it's slightly shorter and doesn't use the weird `Is` pattern:

```
Assert.AreEqual("", new AddressDto { }.FormatForGui());
```